# Sphinx query index: exclude rows containig particular value

Tags: sphinx

I have a Sphinx index with the following columns

| id | article_id | country_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 | 3 |
| 6 | 3 | 4 |
| 7 | 4 | 1 |
| 8 | 4 | 2 |
| 9 | 5 | 1 |

I need to get article_ids which don't contain country_id = 1 at all therefore 2 and 3.

The problem is that Sphinx doesn't support joins, nor sub-queries so I just can create a simple select query and instead of 2 and 3 I get 1, 2, 3, 4 and only 5 is actually excluded.

Is there a way to build a query which will return 2 and 3 in Sphinx?

The simplified Sphinx index looks like that:

```
sql_query_pre = SET @a := 0;

    sql_query = \
\
SELECT \
@a := @a + 1 AS id, \
ase.id AS search_id, \
ase.name, \
ase.article_id, \
af.country_id, \
FROM articles_search ase \
LEFT JOIN articles a ON a.id = ase.article_id \
LEFT JOIN affiliation_article aa ON aa.article_id = ase.article_id \
LEFT JOIN affiliations af ON aa.affiliation_id = af.id \

sql_attr_bigint=country_id
sql_attr_bigint=article_id
}
```

and the query is

`SELECT article_id, WEIGHT() w FROM articles WHERE MATCH('(@name nasicon)') AND country_id != 9 GROUP BY article_id ORDER BY w DESC LIMIT 0, 15 OPTION max_matches = 200`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a clear case for `HAVING`

```
SELECT article_id, WEIGHT() w, SUM(country_id = 1) AS has1
FROM articles
WHERE MATCH('(@name nasicon)')
GROUP BY article_id
HAVING has1 = 0
ORDER BY w DESC
LIMIT 0, 15 OPTION max_matches = 200
```

The SUM counts `country=1` in all rows in group (ie article), and only returns rows, where the article has no country=1 documents.